# Does one Cloudify manager support multiple IaaS?

Tags: cloudify

I wonder if one Cloudify manager (v 3.1 or 3.2) can support multiple IaaS, this includes the following two scenarios:

1- Is it possible to use one Cloudify Manager to deploy applications on multiple IaaS? For example, deploy blueprint1 on open stack deployment 1 and blueprint2 on open stack deployment 2. Or I need one Cloudify Manager for each open stack deployment?

2- Is it possible to distribute the deployment of nodes in a blueprint on several IaaS. For example, if the blueprint has node1, node2 and node3. Is it possible to use one Cloudify manager to deploy the node1 on IaaS 1, node2 on IaaS2 and node3 on IaaS3? Then connect the nodes

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to support more than one IaaS provider per manager, whether they run on the same stack or different ones. For each stack you wish to support, import the given plugin: http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.2/plugin-official-general.html.

Once you've described a multi-cloud topology in a blueprint, creating a deployment and running install should have the effect of creating node instances on each cloud.

For convenience, users typically deploy a manager on the IaaS or PaaS that is hosting their applications, but there's no requirement to do so so long as the networking between clouds and the manager is permitted, wherever it happens to be running.

Comment: If I have two IaaS with same stack (open stack), How could coulidy figure out where to deploy each node? and where can I add the IaaS info( user, name , login , url) after I add the import to blueprint , so that cloudify can use them? It seems for me linke I have to import open stack plugin twice?

Comment: Cloudify will not figure the placement automatically if you use specific IaaS types and plugins. However you can add an abstract type for server or network and bind to it a facade plugin to switch between the underlying plugins. In the deployment inputs you can specify to which IaaS cloudify should switch for this particular application

Comment: Here's an example of what Yaron suggets (for CloudFoundry, in this case): This is for one provider: https://github.com/GigaSpaces-POCs/cfy-pivotal/blob/master/plugin.yaml#L93 and the other provider is on line 101.